# Dynamic Link UTM Tracking Not Working

Tags: marketing-cloud, dynamic, email-tracking

I have a dynamic link in an email that is being pulled from a data extension. The URL is listed below and while the link works correctly, the utm parameters are not tracking in google analytics so we're unable to see data past clicked.

Is there a different way I should be using the dynamic links to get the utm parameters to track?

URL:

`%%cartURL%%&utm_source=transactional&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=CartAbandon&j=%%jobid%%&sfmc_sub=%%SubscriberID%%&l=%%List_%%&u=%%JobURLID%%&mid=%%MemberID%%&jb=%%_JobSubscriberBatchID%%`

Comment: How does the url look when you arrive on the page after clicking the link?

Comment: so this is what the URL looks like in the data extension: https://www.site.com/AbandonedCart? userDetails=XrfPyTwWDnC4KkVC%2b7gWB49DL71eb3ZK8zRfCKQ3sLGPNhaCz235ORqpwwW3n8uyTba7mACoJ5Y%3d

But it redirects based on the user details and what you see once it loads is just: https://www.site.com/Cart

Answer (score 2):

If you're not wanting to wrap *all* the links in every email using the [**Web Analtyics Connector**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_wa_web_analytics_connector.htm&type=5), then I'd recommend this method for appending parameters and values:

```ampscript
%%[

set @params = ""
set @params = concat(@params,"utm_source=transactional")
set @params = concat(@params,"&utm_medium=email")
set @params = concat(@params,"&utm_campaign=CartAbandon")
set @params = concat(@params,"&j=", jobid)
set @params = concat(@params,"&sfmc_sub=", SubscriberID)
set @params = concat(@params,"&l=", List_)
set @params = concat(@params,"&u=", JobURLID)
set @params = concat(@params,"&mid=", MemberID)
set @params = concat(@params,"&jb=", _JobSubscriberBatchID)

set @cartURL = AttributeValue("cartURL")

if indexOf(@cartURL,"?") > 0 then
  set @cartURL = concat(@cartURL, "&", @params)
else
  set @cartURL = concat(@cartURL, "?", @params)
endif

]%%

<!-- some other HTML here -->

<a href="%%=redirectto(@cartURL)=%%" alias="ASC">link</a>
```

**Reference**

- [**attributeValue**](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue)
- [**concat**](https://ampscript.guide/concat)
- [**redirectto**](https://ampscript.guide/redirectto)
- [**indexOf**](https://ampscript.guide/indexof)

Answer (score 0):

The redirect on the dynamic URL was causing the issue - I was able to solve the problem by changing the '&' after the %%carturl%% to a '#' so the new link looks like this:

%%cartURL%%#utm_source=transactional&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=CartAbandon&j=%%jobid%%&sfmc_sub=%%SubscriberID%%&l=%%List_%%&u=%%JobURLID%%&mid=%%MemberID%%&jb=%%_JobSubscriberBatchID%%